# Snowflake stage file path including today's date in it

Tags: sql, yaml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a COPY INTO operation to write to a Snowflake stage. The file path of the Snowflake stage comes from a configuration file written in YAML. How do I pass today's date into the file path of the Snowflake stage using YAML?

My query begins as follows:

COPY INTO @{STAGE_NAME}/{ENVIRONMENT}/{VARIABLE_1}/{VARIABLE_2}_

I want to be able to do turn it into:

COPY INTO @{STAGE_NAME}/{ENVIRONMENT}/{VARIABLE_1}/{VARIABLE_2}/{todays_date}_

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the SET Variable functionality and set today_date as:

```
set today_date = (select current_date());
```

And then use it as any other variable.